# popup facebook feed dialog (for wall posting) in ios xcode 4.3 (storyboard)

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

I am making an app in which I need to integrate a facebook share (feed) dialog. I read all stuff on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/ , and I was able to load facebook share (feed) dialog when the app finished launching. But my problem is that I am using xcode 4.3 i.e storyboard and I want to load facebook feed dialog on button action.

I made another view controller and paste all the stuff of AppDelegate's function
   `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

in its `-(void) viewDidload` and was able to load "login page" and then my "facebook app" page.

After that when I allow permission to my facebook app it does not show "feed dialog"

Here is my viewController.h file

```
 #import "FBConnect.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<FBSessionDelegate,FBDialogDelegate>
{
    Facebook *facebook;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) Facebook *facebook;

@end
```

-Here is my ViewController.m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize facebook=_facebook;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"284727404938450" andDelegate:self];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
        && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
        facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }

    if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
        [facebook authorize:nil];
    }        
}    

- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    [facebook dialog:@"feed" andDelegate:self];    
}
```

but here are two methods which are used in AppDelegate file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [ facebook] handleOpenURL:url]; 
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [ facebook] handleOpenURL:url]; 
}
```

I know that in xib these methods should be:

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
        return [[_ViewController facebook] handleOpenURL:url]; 
    }

// For iOS 4.2+ support
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[_ViewController facebook] handleOpenURL:url]; 
}
```

These method are responsible for popping up a feed dialog for the current "facebook" instance (Facebook *facebook).

My problem is that in the storyboard we dont have a "window" and view controller intances so my guess is that these two methods are not being called for my current viewController's "facebook" instance. How can I call these two functions for my "facebook" instance, where my viewController is not an instance of AppDelegate file?

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a reference of your viewcontroller in the app delegate's _viewcontroller before using Facebook (or calling these delegate functions).

Your view controller's viewdidload() will look like as below:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{ 



[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]._viewComtroller = self; // pass reference to the appdalegate



//   Other code (or call the facebook function here)
```

}

It will be working

Answer (score 0):

Be careful because you are defining an ivar named "facebook" and a property named "facebook" that creates another ivar named "_facebook". Then on your code your are working with the ivar "facebook", so when you call `[_ViewController facebook]` you are accessing the property (ivar _facebook) and not the ivar "facebook" that you initialized.

I don't think this is the answer you were looking for but it seemed important to point out.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a few Facebook related delegates and that you're not putting them all in your main app delegate as the online tutorial instructs:

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

Answer (score 0):

Well one solution could implement the Facebook delegate methods in the AppDelegate, then in your viewController in the viewDidLoad method, or the method you prefer, use

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate= (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.facebook authorize:permissions];
```

where permissions is an array with the permissions you need. That should work and the methods

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [ facebook] handleOpenURL:url]; 
 }

 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
return [ facebook] handleOpenURL:url]; 
 }
```

are performed.